# Tensorflow: Finetune pretrained model on new dataset with different number of classes

Tags: tensorflow

How can I finetune a pretrained model in tensorflow on a new dataset? In Caffe I can simply rename the last layer and set some parameters for random initialization. Is something similar possible in tensorflow?

Say I have a checkpoint file (`deeplab_resnet.ckpt`) and some code that sets up the computational graph in which I can modify the last layer such that it has the same number of ouputs as the new dataset has classes.

Then I try to start the session like this:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess.run(init)

trainable = tf.trainable_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=trainable, max_to_keep=40)
saver.restore(sess, 'ckpt_path/deeplab_resnet.ckpt')
```

However this gives me an error when calling the `saver.restore` function since it expects the exact same graph structure as the the one it was saved from. 
How can I only load all weights except for the last layer from the `'ckpt_path/deeplab_resnet.ckpt'` file?
I also tried changing the `Classification` layer name but no luck there either...

I'm using the [tensorflow-deeplab-resnet model](https://github.com/DrSleep/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet)

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. Do you want to *modify* a layer i.e. use it but differently (changing shape etc) or do you want to use all the model BUT the layer (using a brand new layer). pltrdy

Comment: Both (as usally done in finetuning). I take an old model replace the last layer with one that fits the new number of classes of the new dataset. Then this last layer needs to be initialized randomly. I guess @Alexey Romanovs answer is already half of the solution. The only part thats missing is the explicit random initialisation of a layer when the network was imported from a former caffemodel as it's the case in `tensorflow-deeplab-resnet`

Comment: @mcExchange, please complete the answer below with complete solution and/or approve the solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the names of the variables that you want to restore.

So, you can get a list of all of the variables in the model and filter out the variables of the last layer:

```
all_vars = tf.all_variables()
var_to_restore = [v for v in all_vars if not v.name.startswith('xxx')]

saver = tf.train.Saver(var_to_restore)
```

See the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variables/#choosing_which_variables_to_save_and_restore) for the details.

Alternatively, you can try to load the whole model an create a new "branch" out of the layer before the last and use it in the cost function during the training.

Comment: `v.name.startswith('xxx')` was a good hint. Although the network does not crash anymore the training it is not yet converging / the loss not decreasing. Do I have to tell the network explicitly to randomly initialize the layers that were left out? (By the way I had to use `all_vars = tf.trainable_variables()` instead of `all_vars = tf.all_variables()`

Comment: Was you able to train the model without initializing the new variables? TensorFlow should give you an error if you try to use an initialized variable.

You can try to use `tf.variables_initializer(var_list)` but it's strange that TensorFlow allowed you to train the model without initializing all the variables.

Comment: The problem here is probably that the TF graph was not manually created but converted from a caffemodel. So I don't have explicit Variable definitions like `myVar = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([...], stddev=...),name="...")`. I probably have to get select these variable via their name and tell TF explicitly to initialize them randomly. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: You do have the variables for your new layer, correct? For them you can `tf.variables_initializer` to initialize your new variables. `added_vars = [v for v in ...], init_op = tf.variables_initializer(added_vars), sees.run(init_op)`

Comment: Well I'm already doing a `init = tf.initialize_all_variables()` and `sess.run(init)` before restoring the individual variables. So I guess all variables should have been initialized by then. I have also a feeling the the last layer might not be attached to the rest of the network due to the partial restauration. At least in tensorboard, there are no lines between the previous last and the last layer... I will check that again